# Notation for annihilator with ring and module interchanged?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module. For a subset $S\subseteq R$, the set
$$\{m\in M\mid (\forall s\in S)[sm=0]\}$$
is clearly a submodule of $M$. Is there a name or notation for it? It is essentially the definition of annihilator with ring and module interchanged.

Comment: I saw it denoted by $Ann(S)$.

Comment: It can be expressed as the intersection of a bunch of kernels, one for each $s\in S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notations $(0:_M S)$ and $\operatorname{Ann}_M(S)$ are both commonly used for this submodule. I'm not sure there's a standard name, but I've heard it informally referred to as "the annihilator of $S$ in $M$" before. More generally, if $N$ is a submodule of $M$ and $S \subseteq R$ (of course, we can always replace $S$ by the ideal it generates), we write $(N:_M S):=\{m \in M \mid Sm \subseteq N\}$.

Comment: @rschwieb Ah yes, thanks; I misstated it.

Comment: Oh, well all good then :)